# c++ Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ToSend22' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I have no idea why is that happening - when ever I call this function I have and send TCP messages to the client, I've got this:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ToSend22' was corrupted.
Whenever the client is disconnected. ToSend22 is STD string which I am doing

```
const char *ToSend288 = ToSend22.c_str();
Client.Send(ToSend288, ToSend22.size());
```

Why is that happening? Thanks.

Comment: What API is Client.Send?

Comment: SFML http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the two lines of code you posted. The problem with your code is elsewhere. One of the most difficult things for newbies to learn about C++ programming is that just because an error shows up in one place in your code, does **NOT** mean that the error is in that place in your code. The error usually happened some time earlier on. So post a bit more code if you want us to help find the problem.

Comment: I have 5000 lines of code here, I can't post them all.. No i actually mean it, it's a game server that is done, only that's bug. What should I do?

Comment: Is the Send method your code?  If so, post that since that's probably where the error occurs.

Comment: First I'd try a debugger. If that isn't helpful or productive I would start cutting code, starting at what you think are the most likely problem areas. At some point as you cut more and more code the bug will go away. At that point there's a fair chance you've found the problem code. It may then be obvious but otherwise post the problem code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `Client.Send` is modifying the `char*` buffer you are passing to it.
Or other local variable in same function is being overwritten somehow, which is affecting `ToSend22` variable. Array or pointer mis-use is definitely involved in this function.

Please post some more code.